# Change the default IP address of a CentOS 6 dedicated server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ip, centos6

I have a dedicated box running CentOS 6. I'd like to change the default IP address, I googled a lot and I found this suggestion:

(1) Run these two commands via SSH:

```
sudo -n ifconfig eth0 down
sudo -n ifconfig eth0 up NEW_IP
```

(2) Change Apache's ServerName directive to the new IP address in `httpd.conf`, ie.

```
ServerName 111.222.333.44:80
```

(3) Restart apache

(4) Change any domain pointing to this server/old IP address to point to the new one.

I'm going to do this on a live server, so I'd like to know if these instructions are correct before I proceed (I don"t wanna screw things up)

**Can someone please confirm (or correct me if I'm wrong) if this is the way to go?**

---

### EDIT

`apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` gave me a long list that looks like this:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server domain1.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1015)
     port 80 namevhost domain1.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1015)
             alias www.domain1.com
             wild alias *.domain1.com
     port 80 namevhost domain2.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1021)
             wild alias *.domain1.org
     port 80 namevhost domain3.info (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1033)
             wild alias *.domain3.info
etc...

Syntax OK
```

Comment: Find a non-live server to learn on first. You can get a temporary machine from a cloud provider for mere cents on the hour. That's way cheaper than hosing your production box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to modify **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX** and restart the network service

```
# service network restart
```

Comment: I think I cried victory too fast :( I followed your instructions but now the websites hosted on that server are now unreachable. I restarted apache & waited several hours for propagation (I'm using google dns), am I missing something?

Comment: What about listening? Just show output of the apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS (add the output to the question)

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question with `apachectl` result

Comment: Never mind, websites are now working for me. Thanks man!